# Как при клике на счетчик увеличивать число кликов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как при клике на счетчик увеличивать число кликов?

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="click">Кликов: 0</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
button:before {
  content: 'Кликов: '
}
```

```html
<button onclick="this.innerHTML++">0</button>
```

Comment: то же самое будет с addEventListener, а чем не угодил onclick? =)

Comment: @ЛёхаБунин а аргументация какая?

Comment: @ЛёхаБунин все верно, есть всякие mvc и так далее, каждому свое,  у инлайн атрибутов есть одно приемущество - если вы вручную манипулируете dom, такие слушатели не слетают при изменении innerHTML, а так все зависит от контекста, для генерируемых элементов часто удобнее сделать инлайн атрибут, чем заморачиваться с навешиванием функций

Answer (score 1):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("click"),
  count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  button.innerHTML = "Кликов: " + count;
};
```

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="click">Кликов: 0</button>
```